# How to find root of a function accepting error on f(x) instead of x?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

I have a function like e. g.:

```py
amountOfCalls = 0

def myFunc(x):
    global amountOfCalls
    amountOfCalls+=1
    y = x ** 3 + x -5
    return y
```

and want to find the root of it (i. e.: find the value of `x` where `f(x) == 0`).

If I use one of `scipy` optimizers like [ridder](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.ridder.html), I can set only the relative or absolute tolerance of `x` but not of `f(x)`.

Is there any possibility/alternative, where I could tell the optimizer to stop when `abs(f(x))` has become smaller than e.g. `0.2` (as an absolute tolerance)?

Remark: As my function is in reality a black-box function, I have to stick to an optimizing approach (so analytical alternatives unfortunately do not work).

Comment: Do you know if the function is linear or not?

Comment: I have to assume that it is not linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `scipy.optimize.root` for achieving this as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html).

You could use any of the mentioned methods on the above-mentioned link. I am choosing `broyden1`. In this method, you can set `fatol` to `0.2` as it is the absolute tolerance for the residual.

```py
from scipy.optimize import root

amountOfCalls = 0

def myFunc(x):
    global amountOfCalls
    amountOfCalls+=1
    y = x ** 3 + x -5
    return y

x0 = 3
res = root(myFunc, x0, method='broyden1', options={'disp':True, 'fatol':0.2})
print(res)
```

The above code will terminate when `myFunc(x) < 0.2`.

If you want your condition to be explicitly `abs(f(x)) < 0.2`, then you could use the *callback* function as it is called at each iteration. You can then check at each iteration, if the condition is met and raise an `Error` to stop the root-finding method as follows:

```py
from scipy.optimize import root

class Error(Exception):
    pass

class AlmostReachedZeroError(Error):
    pass

class rootFinder():

    def __init__(self):
        self.amountOfCalls = 0

    def fun(self, x0):
        y = x0 ** 3 + x0 - 5
        return y

    def callback(self, x, f):
        # callback to terminate if condition is met
        self.amountOfCalls+=1

        if abs(self.fun(x[0])) < 0.2:
            print("Current x: ", x[0], "Current fval: ", f[0],
                  "Iterations: ", self.amountOfCalls)
            raise AlmostReachedZeroError("Terminating optimization: limit reached")

    def find_root(self):
        x0 = 3
        opt = root(self.fun, x0, method='broyden1', callback=self.callback,
                   options={'disp':True, 'ftol':0.2})
        return opt

rf = rootFinder()
res = rf.find_root()
print(res)
```

The above code will terminate the root-finding method if `abs(f(x)) < 0.2`, and will produce an `Error`. Also, the current *x* value, the current *fval*, and the *iterations* that the method took will be printed.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I think that even your first code example is usable for my initial question, when we wrap `myFunc()` with another function that delivers `abs(myFunc())`. But the hint for the callback is very helpful indeed!

Comment: Yes, the first approach is much simpler but with _callback_, you can do much more.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but this should do the trick:

```
    global amountOfCalls
    amountOfCalls+=1
    y = x ** 3 + x -5
    if y == 0:
        return x
    return y
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that you misunderstood the question. The function will always return y. The question is just how to stop the optimizing algorithm once `f(x)` is close enough to `0`.